# Advanced DataGridView on manual columns

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to put a filter on datagridview with ADGV (https://www.nuget.org/packages/ADGV/). However, when I create Datetime value columns by manually the filter does not display filtering by the Year, Month, and Day values.
When the column is created automatically, in runtime this columns shows exactly how to filter.
I want to create these DateTime value columns by manually. What should I do?

```
    private void btnchonLop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string TenLop = "Null"; string MaCLB = "Null"; int LichHoc = 3;
        adgvHocSinhDuDK.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        adgvHocSinhDuDK.AutoGenerateContextFilters = true;

        if (adgvDanhSachLop.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in adgvDanhSachLop.SelectedRows)
            {
                 TenLop = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                 MaCLB = row.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
                 LichHoc = (int)row.Cells[5].Value;
            }
            DataTable dt = HocSinhServices.LayHocSinhTheoLopDangKy(TenLop, MaCLB, LichHoc);
            bdHocSinhDuDieuKien.DataSource = dt; // 
            adgvHocSinhDuDK.EnableFilter(clNgayNhapHoc); // Enabled Fitleter on NgayNhapHocColumn
        }
        else return;
    }
```

[image: With by manually]

### By manually column

[image]

### By Auto column

Comment: Can you explain what your code is doing? What is `bdHocSinhDuDieuKien` ?

Comment: this is my bindingsource, and gridview datasource = bdHocSinhDuDieuKien

Comment: How many rows do you get in `dt`? Where in the code are you adding column manually?

Comment: All are 4 rows, no difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and I've got an answer for you: You have to set up the column `ValueType` BEFORE adding it to your `AdvancedDataGridView`.

Somewhere in your `designer.cs`, you have the declaration of columns and adgv, then you set the parameters of the adgv and then the parameters of the columns (default design in Visual Studio).

In the code, follow this:

1. First set the parameters of your column and add the `ValueType`:

example :
   `this.ContactDate.ValueType = typeof(System.DateTime);`

2. Then add the column in your adgv

All because the filter of DateTime is activated on event "OnColumnAdd": if the ValueType is not DateTime, you won't get the right filter.